# Html online reload without pressing ctrl+f5

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling with this for a while now, whenever I upload a script to my website, it doesn't show up until I press Ctrl + F5 or any other alternative, I know it works but if this website of mine gets a publicity, its not like I can tell all the people to go on a computer and press Ctrl+F5 or something, its dumb, I want it to be like all the other websites, I press refresh, (not ctrl+f5) and all the new updates are loaded! if there is some sort of HTML, CSS, code that could help will be well appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force the browser to reload cached CSS/JS files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118884/how-to-force-the-browser-to-reload-cached-css-js-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
<script src="script.js">
```

you could use

```
<script src="script.js?version=1">
```

By increasing the number `1` each time you upload a new script, you are bypassing the cache.

Instead of `1`, you could also create a random number in backend. For instance in PHP:

```
<script src="script.js?version=<?= time(); ?>">
```

Comment: Thank you! I have not learned javascript yet, but I put ?version=1     <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css?version=1"> in here, and each time I edited the browser and ran it on my other console, it showed up.. so thank you a lot! it worked like a charm